# Connect to MySQL using encrypted password

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have a question that I see asked a lot, but have not found any specific answers to.

I'm creating a PHP (frontend) and C++ (backend) application. Both ends connect to the same database using a common .cfg file, in which the username and password to connect to the database are stored in plain text. This makes me uncomfortable. How can I encrypt that password? Is it even possible?

Comment: Generally, for any application that stores data within a system that the user has full access, perfect security is not possible.

What you can do is to encrypt the password so it's hard for someone to hack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hypothetical case that someone can access the file and see the encrypted password, in the same way that person could also make a connection and destroy the database. Only you can see that file so the password does not need to be encrypted.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and probably why I never found an answer to it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

PHP isn't a front end language. It's a server side language similar to C#. Your config file will stay on the server, unless you allow your server to, well, serve that file when requested by a client. You don't need to encrypt the username or password, because only you and your employees should ever see it.

Comment: PHP can be used for the front-end, for example a Windows client.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, PHP can be used to deliver front end content, but it's still a server side interpreted language. With PHP, you still need to deliver HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to a browser or other visual tool to interact with a user. The various frameworks might do this for you, but PHP is still run on a server, not the client's computer. The fact that the OP can even access the DB through their PHP means that it's running server side, not client side.